# SQL Query for summing up values from rows within specific time period (within ID)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to sum up values (Amount2) from rows within a specific time period (datediff 18hours or 22hours) and also need to know how many rows were used. This summing the values has to be done within the ID number. Can anyone help with this?

First rows of the Table T1:

```
ID  PickupDateTime          Amount2 DifferenceToPrevious
1   2019-04-02 04:44:19.000 6458    0d 00:13:17:000
1   2019-04-02 04:31:02.000 5385    0d 02:34:50:000
1   2019-04-02 01:56:12.000 1545    0d 18:06:18:000
1   2019-04-01 07:49:54.000 3466    1d 02:23:51:000
1   2019-03-31 05:26:03.000 7505    0d 00:13:53:000
1   2019-03-31 05:12:10.000 5080    0d 03:28:18:000
1   2019-03-31 01:43:52.000 1166    0d 18:02:49:000
1   2019-03-30 07:41:03.000 2991    1d 02:39:49:000
1   2019-03-29 05:01:14.000 7065    0d 00:13:11:000
2   2019-04-01 04:56:21.000 9518    1d 23:52:21:000
2   2019-03-30 05:04:00.000 9638    2d 00:34:29:000
2   2019-03-28 04:29:31.000 9499    1d 23:28:47:000
2   2019-03-26 05:00:44.000 10117   2d 00:03:41:000
2   2019-03-24 04:57:03.000 9933    1d 23:50:06:000
2   2019-03-22 05:06:57.000 9869    2d 00:25:01:000
```

What I need is script that sums Amount2 from rows where PickupDate time is within 18 hours or 22hours, calculates also the rows which are summed (this has to be done within ID).

```
PickupDateTime  Amount2 DifferenceToPrevious    Amount2_18h Rows_18 Amount2_22h Rows_22
2019-04-02 04:44:19.000 6458    0d 00:13:17:000 13388   3   16854   4
2019-04-02 04:31:02.000 5385    0d 02:34:50:000 6930    2   10396   3
2019-04-02 01:56:12.000 1545    0d 18:06:18:000 1545    1   12516   3
2019-04-01 07:49:54.000 3466    1d 02:23:51:000 3466    1   3466    1
2019-03-31 05:26:03.000 7505    0d 00:13:53:000 13751   3   16742   4
2019-03-31 05:12:10.000 5080    0d 03:28:18:000 6246    2   9237    3
2019-03-31 01:43:52.000 1166    0d 18:02:49:000 1166    1   4157    2
2019-03-30 07:41:03.000 2991    1d 02:39:49:000 2991    1   2991    1
2019-04-01 04:56:21.000 9518    1d 23:52:21:000 9518    1   9518    1
2019-03-30 05:04:00.000 9638    2d 00:34:29:000 9638    1   9638    1
2019-03-28 04:29:31.000 9499    1d 23:28:47:000 9499    1   9499    1
2019-03-26 05:00:44.000 10117   2d 00:03:41:000 10117   1   10117   1
2019-03-24 04:57:03.000 9933    1d 23:50:06:000 9933    1   9933    1
2019-03-22 05:06:57.000 9869    2d 00:25:01:000 9869    1   9869    1
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question - how can PickupDateTime appear in the results when you want to sum Amount2? Do you want to group by the PickupDateTime as well? That doesn't make much sense. Grouping by something that changes every split second is like no grouping at all.

Answer (score 1):

Test data:

```
declare @tbl table (ID int,  PickupDateTime datetime2(3), Amount2 int)
insert into @tbl values
(1,   '2019-04-02 04:44:19.000', 6458),
(1,   '2019-04-02 04:31:02.000', 5385),
(1,   '2019-04-02 01:56:12.000', 1545),
(1,   '2019-04-01 07:49:54.000', 3466),
(1,   '2019-03-31 05:26:03.000', 7505),
(1,   '2019-03-31 05:12:10.000', 5080),
(1,   '2019-03-31 01:43:52.000', 1166),
(1,   '2019-03-30 07:41:03.000', 2991),
(1,   '2019-03-29 05:01:14.000', 7065),
(2,   '2019-04-01 04:56:21.000', 9518),
(2,   '2019-03-30 05:04:00.000', 9638),
(2,   '2019-03-28 04:29:31.000', 9499),
(2,   '2019-03-26 05:00:44.000', 10117),
(2,   '2019-03-24 04:57:03.000', 9933),
(2,   '2019-03-22 05:06:57.000', 9869);
```

Query to get your desired results. The key is to use subqueries with appropriate `where` clauses:

```
select t1.*,
       (select count(*) from @tbl t2
        where dateadd(hour, -18, t1.pickupdatetime) <= t2.PickupDateTime
        and t1.PickupDateTime >= t2.PickupDateTime
        and t1.id = t2.id) Rows_18,
       (select sum(Amount2) from @tbl t2
        where dateadd(hour, -18, t1.pickupdatetime) <= t2.PickupDateTime
        and t1.PickupDateTime >= t2.PickupDateTime
        and t1.id = t2.id) Amount2_18,
       (select count(*) from @tbl t2
        where dateadd(hour, -22, t1.pickupdatetime) <= t2.PickupDateTime
        and t1.PickupDateTime >= t2.PickupDateTime
        and t1.id = t2.id) Rows_22,
       (select sum(Amount2) from @tbl t2
        where dateadd(hour, -22, t1.pickupdatetime) <= t2.PickupDateTime
        and t1.PickupDateTime >= t2.PickupDateTime
        and t1.id = t2.id) Amount2_22
from @tbl t1
order by t1.PickupDateTime desc
```

Comment: Beat me to it! I did it the same except for using temp tables instead.

Comment: Works, but it's rather inefficient, requiring a scan per subquery, which could get very slow. It's doable with just one additional scan instead of four, see my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

While @Michał Turczyn's query will provide the right data, it will also require 5 scans (1 main + 4 per subquery). You can do it more efficiently with just one additional scan:

```
declare @tbl table (ID int,  PickupDateTime datetime2(3), Amount2 int)
insert into @tbl values
(1,   '2019-04-02 04:44:19.000', 6458),
(1,   '2019-04-02 04:31:02.000', 5385),
(1,   '2019-04-02 01:56:12.000', 1545),
(1,   '2019-04-01 07:49:54.000', 3466),
(1,   '2019-03-31 05:26:03.000', 7505),
(1,   '2019-03-31 05:12:10.000', 5080),
(1,   '2019-03-31 01:43:52.000', 1166),
(1,   '2019-03-30 07:41:03.000', 2991),
(1,   '2019-03-29 05:01:14.000', 7065),
(2,   '2019-04-01 04:56:21.000', 9518),
(2,   '2019-03-30 05:04:00.000', 9638),
(2,   '2019-03-28 04:29:31.000', 9499),
(2,   '2019-03-26 05:00:44.000', 10117),
(2,   '2019-03-24 04:57:03.000', 9933),
(2,   '2019-03-22 05:06:57.000', 9869);

SELECT pickup.*, subCalc.*
  FROM @tbl pickup
 CROSS 
 APPLY (SELECT SUM(incl.include18) AS count18
             , SUM(incl.include18 * sub.Amount2) AS amount18
             , SUM(incl.include22) AS count22
             , SUM(incl.include22 * sub.Amount2) AS amount22
          FROM @tbl sub
         CROSS
         APPLY (SELECT IIF(DATEADD(HOUR, -18, pickup.pickupdatetime) <= sub.PickupDateTime, 1, 0) AS include18
                     , IIF(DATEADD(HOUR, -22, pickup.pickupdatetime) <= sub.PickupDateTime, 1, 0) AS include22
             ) incl
         WHERE pickup.PickupDateTime >= sub.PickupDateTime
           AND pickup.id = sub.id
     ) subCalc
ORDER BY pickup.PickupDateTime DESC
```

[Working example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1eaa3f5be1427ddb6ec5b7f883eb8000).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sum(Amount2) as sum_amount_2, Count(*) as n_lines_summed
From table
WHERE PickupDateTime between DateDiff(HOUR, -22, GetDate()) and DateDiff(HOUR, -18, GetDate())
Group by Id
```

something like that? quite simple, I think.

Answer (score 0):

you need somethings like that?

```
select * from 
(    Select PickupDateTime  sum(Amount2) as sum_amount_18, Count(*) as n_lines_summed18
    From table
    WHERE PickupDateTime <=  DateDiff(HOUR, -18, GetDate())
    Group by PickupDateTime  )X join 
(    Select PickupDateTime  sum(Amount2) as sum_amount_22, Count(*) as n_lines_summed22
    From table
    WHERE PickupDateTime <=  DateDiff(HOUR, -22, GetDate())
    Group by PickupDateTime  )y on X.PickupDateTime  =  Y.PickupDateTime
```